# ggvis Map & Tooltips

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, dplyr, ggvis

I am trying to layer on tooltips to a map of the US, but wherever I hover... it displays the same data.  In addition, the data is wrong.  I'm thinking that it is passing through the factor values and not the character value.  I tried taking tips from the movie explorer example - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html - but, it's not working as I hoped.  Any hints or clues I should look into?

Update: I've determined that you can only pass through arguments that are being called into the `ggvis` function.  So, if my tooltip function included `region`, `long`, & `lat`, all of them would appear in the tooltip.  Since `Population` and `Income` do not appear anywhere in the function, it is not passing them through.  I'm still lost on how to proceed, but any ideas would be awesome! :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    #numericInput("n", "n", 1),
    ggvisOutput("map")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    statesData <- reactive({

      states <- data.frame(state.x77)
      states$region <- row.names(state.x77) %>% tolower
      row.names(states) <- NULL

      all_states <- map_data("state") %>%
        mutate(region = tolower(region)) %>%
        left_join(states)

      all_states_unique <- all_states %>%
        select(region, Population, Income, Illiteracy, Life.Exp, Murder, HS.Grad, Frost, Area) %>%
        unique

      states_tooltip <- function(x) {
        if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
        if (is.null(x$region)) return(NULL)

        # Pick out the movie with this ID
        allStates <- isolate(all_states_unique)
        state <- allStates[allStates$region == x$region, ]

        paste0("<b>", state$region, "</b><br>",
               state$Population, "<br>",
               state$Income

        )
      }

      all_states %>%
        arrange(group, order) %>%
        ggvis(x = ~long, y = ~lat) %>%
        layer_paths(fill = ~region, stroke := .2) %>%
        add_tooltip(states_tooltip, "hover")

    })

    statesData %>% bind_shiny('map')    

  }

)
```

Comment: Might be related to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493278/ggvis-density-plot-with-tooltip/24498139#24498139)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index to the dataframe you want to pull the tooltip data from:

```
 state$id <- 1:nrow(state)
```

ggvis takes a "key" argument to facilitate this kind of tooltip:

```
 ggvis(x = ~long, y = ~lat, key := ~id) %>%
```

I tried figuring out that movie example and didn't find it very helpful. This always works for me:

```
 add_tooltip(function(x) {
             row <- state[state$id == x$key,]
             paste0("<b>", row[,"region"], "</b><br>",
                    row[,"Population"], "<br>",
                    row[,"Income"]
                    )})
```

As for the issue w/ the tooltip always coming up the same, I don't know for sure but think it's due to the order of your layers in the ggvis command. Had a similar problem where I had some polygons layered on top of a scatterplot. It kept trying to draw the tooltip for the polygons (which covered the whole chart) when what I wanted was the individual points to display the tooltip. By reversing their order in the ggvis command (ie layer_points() %>% layer_shapes()) I got it to work.

Comment: Hey Brick, thanks for the response!  This doesn't quite solve what I need, but it's definitely providing a little guidance.

Comment: Hey Brick, finally got it to work with some more tinkering.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is quite late but for future reference and others that stumble across this page. If your dataframe has been converted using fortify and has the group variable then this may be equivalent to the State level. Group can then be used to filter for the tooltip as it is in the ggvis command. That then allowed me to gain access to other variables I wanted.

In my problem I couldn't use the key solution because I was creating the plot to react to numerous years. So to change what you have above states_tooltip would become:

```
       states_tooltip <- function(x){
 row <- allstates[allstates$group==x$group,]  %>%
     select(region, Population, Income)  %>% unique
 paste0("<b>", row[,"region"], "</b><br>",
                row[,"Population"], "<br>",
                row[,"Income"]
                )})
```